# handle jwt token expiration and get the new token returned by backend

Tags: angular

I'm getting token from the back end server and I'm storing it in local storage, and using interceptor that handles the authorization in every HTTP request, but when the token is expired my back end server is returning a new one but I'm not able to get it and replace the old token in local storage with the new one.

here is my interceptor angular:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public router: Router) {
  }

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (request.responseType === 'blob') {
      return next.handle(request)
        .catch((error: any) => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              if (error.error instanceof Blob && error.headers.get('content-type').startsWith('application/json')) {
                  error = new HttpErrorResponse({
                      error: {message: "An error has occured and file cannot be downloaded"},
                      headers: error.headers,
                      status: error.status,
                      statusText: error.statusText,
                      url: error.url
                  });
              }
          }

          return Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }

    let token = localStorage.getItem('Token');

    if (token) {
      request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', token) });
      localStorage.setItem('Token', token);
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        var token = event.headers.get('Authorization');
        if(token) {
          request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', token) });
          localStorage.setItem('Token', token);
        }
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      }
    });


  }
}
```

and there is my login function inside a service:

```
login() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.auth}security/login`,{withCredentials: true})
        .map((res:any) => {return res})
        .pipe((catchError(this.handleError)))
}
```

the back end server returns a new token while the user is active on the application, and I want to compare every time the token returned in the response header with the token that I send if they are equals I do nothing, but if they are different I want replace the token in local storage by the new one.any help please.

Comment: The right behaviour is to make your httpCall, then when getting a 401, park the httpCall in an array of Requests, then invoke another api using your expired token and ask for a new token (witch is called a refresh token). Then set this new refresh Token in localstorage and relaunch parked api calls.

Answer (score 0):

the solution in the back end is to send a token for exemple every 5min while user is active on the application,and when user is not active after ffor exemple 30min the token is expired,so the solution i want is just compare the token in response header and the token in request header in every request,if they are equals ===>do nothing,else replace the old token by the new one,any help pleeaasee?